# JS Regex (Regular Expression) for "page=anynumber"

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove substrings containing the word "page=" followed by number.
Ex.

```
s= "aaaapage=500";
```

Should be

```
s = "page=500"
```

I tried

```
  s =  s.replace(/&page=\d/g,"");
```

and

```
  s =  s.replace(/&page=[\d]+/g,"");
```

to no avail

Answer (score 1):

You can match text before and after while capturing the `page=[digits]`:

```js
s= "aaaapage=500";
document.write(s.replace(/.*(page=\d+).*/, '$1') + "<br/>");
// or with multiline input
s= "a\na\naapage=500text\nnewline";
document.write(s.replace(/[\s\S]*(page=\d+)[\s\S]*/, '$1'));
```

This is good when we only have 1 `page=[digits]`.

When we have more, use `exec`:

```js
var re = /page=\d+/g; 
var str = 'apageaaaapage=500apageaaaapage=210';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.write(m[0] + "<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Note that I am not suggesting any word boundaries or non-word boundaries since I am not sure what your input strings may look like. I am using `g` with `exec` to get all matches in case there are more than 1, it is important.

Comment: One more comment: your attempts did not work because `s =  s.replace(/&page=\d/g,"");` tried to remove `&page=[one digit]` from the `s` string, and `s =  s.replace(/&page=[\d]+/g,"");` tried to remove 1 or more occurrences of `&page=[1 or more digits]` from `s`. Since you want to keep the `page=digits`, you cannot match it, or as I did, you need to capture it and then restore with a backreference.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized

```
s =  s.replace(/&page=[\d]+/g,"");
```

actually works

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the word chars which exists before `page=`

```
 s.replace(/\w*(page=\d+)/g,"$1");
```